# Cannot run .exe files

Tags: linux, windows, executable

Normally my Linux OS allows me to create runnable executables (like *a.out*), but when I attempt to download an *.exe* from the Internet, it basically is permission restricted (neither user has execution (`-x`) rights). The problem is, when I change the file permissions with either `chmod u+x` or `chmod 777`, and I try to run the program, I always get this error message:

```
run detectors: unable to find an interpreter for ./[file_name].exe
```

where the *[file_name]* stands for the name of the file. Since my Linux experience and knowledge are very weak, and I did some research but haven't found anyone with this exact problem, any help would be highly appreciated!

PS. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 32-bit

Comment: What does `file [file_name].exe` and `ldd [file_name].exe` tell you?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run Windows executables on Linux.  This won't work.

Comment: As the answer said, you are trying to use a Windows executable in Linux.  Won't work without WINE and maybe even not then.  What program are you trying to run? There is probably a native Linux equivalent...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is totally normal. `.exe` files are Windows executables, and are not meant to be executed natively by any Linux system.

However, there's a program called Wine which allows you to run `.exe` files by translating Windows API calls to calls your Linux kernel can understand.

To run a `.exe` program you first need to install Wine.

To do so you can follow the [Official Wine installation tutorial for Ubuntu](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), or [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine).

Then you need to open a terminal, go to the directory where you stored your `.exe` file and run `wine your_file.exe`.

Some programs don't work properly, others don't work at all. To check whether a program will run properly under Wine or if it requires some tweaks, take a look at your program entry in the [AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/).

Comment: Oh, this may really be the issue indeed... Gonna follow your instructions :)

Comment: It works perfectly for now, thank you very much!